# Lua Array shuffle not working

Tags: lua, shuffle, lua-table

I was working on a script to randomize the data inside of my array but I get and error
that says

```
unexpected symbol near "#"
```

When I go to that line, and I remove the "#" I get

```
attempt to perform arithmetic on local `n' (a table value)
```

Here is my shuffle function

```
function shuffle(array)
    local array = array
    local n = #array
    local j
    local random = math.random
    for i=n-1, 1, -1 do
        j = random(i)
        array[j],array[i] = array[i],array[j]
    end
    return array
end
```

and here is what I am trying to randomize

```
shuffle(new_players)
for name,character in pairs(new_players) do
    if (character.inside == true and character.death == 0) then
        local player = getPlayerByName(name, map_copy)
        if (player ~= nil) then
            addState(player)
            break
        end
    end
end
```

Here is my array

```
new_players= { }
new_players[charName] = { death = 0, inside= true }
```

Any help? If i am doing something completely wrong?

Comment: You can't shuffle an associative array.

Comment: Why `break` after `addState`?  Do you need only one random player?

Comment: Why do you have the line `local array = array`?

Comment: Which version of Lua are using?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yes only need one random player.

Comment: @derkyjadex Should that not be there?

Comment: @DerickJones Logically it does nothing. I wondered if it was supposed to be some kind performance optimisation, but `array` is already `local`. So unless I'm mistaken, it does nothing at all.

Comment: @derkyjadex it does create a new local variable called `array` and assigns the value of `array` to it. It is redundant but it will do *something*.

Answer (score 3):

1) Try change `charName` from string to a number.

2) For shuffle you can use this code:

```
function swap(array, index1, index2)
    array[index1], array[index2] = array[index2], array[index1]
end

function shuffle(array)
    local counter = #array
    while counter > 1 do
        local index = math.random(counter)
        swap(array, index, counter)
        counter = counter - 1
    end
end
```

Comment: Do I use this after I change charName from string to number? Or does not matter?

Comment: As you wish. In your code, there are strange things, like `local array = array`, which contribute to the code ambiguous behavior. Your and my functions are very similar, but my reads better. P.S. Sorry for Google-translating.

Answer (score 3):

If your Lua version is `< 5.1` then there is no `#` operator. Use `table.getn` instead:

```
local n = table.getn(array);
```

(Update) Note that your function, while it *does* shuffle the items around, it does not really shuffle all elements. Also since you reduce the range with each iteration, you will almost certainly swap the first 10% of your array around multiple times. Now swapping them multiple times is not bad by itself, but that you are, by comparison, almost never swapping the other elements is.

So one option to solve this would be to always use the same range for your random variable. And I would go even further and select two random indexes to swap:

```
function shuffle(array)
    local n, random, j = table.getn(array), math.random
    for i=1, n do
        j,k = random(n), random(n)
        array[j],array[k] = array[k],array[j]
    end
    return array
end
```

The other option would be to select random elements from the source array and put them into a new output array:

```
local rnd,trem,getn,ins = math.random,table.remove,table.getn,table.insert;
function shuffle(a)
    local r = {};
    while getn(a) > 0 do
        ins(r, trem(a, rnd(getn(a))));
    end
    return r;
end
```